# Lastwritetime on an object using exact time not only the date

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a huge filesystem to copy on the 12th of April. My approach is to copy all files today and on the 12th. I only copy the files which are modified later.

I only check on the folder level like this:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\mypm.com\www\ddf\*\ | where-object {
  $_.LastWriteTime -gt (09.04.2014)
}
```

How can I add an exact time to the date? I know it is possible but I checked the output of `select lastwritetime` and wrote it in the same structure, no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a System.DateTime object using the `get-date` cmdlet

```
$date = get-date "09.04.2014 8:00 AM"
```

And use it like this

```
Get-ChildItem C:\mypm.com\www\ddf*\ | where-object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt $date}
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176845.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use a complete date/time in a string:

```
... | where { $_.LastWriteTime -gt '2014-04-09 22:41' }
```

Conversion rules in this case state that the string on the right side will be converted to a `DateTime`, thus working as expected.